# How can we get visitor location using google API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=API KEy"></script>  
 if(google.loader.ClientLocation) {
      visitor_lat = google.loader.ClientLocation.latitude;
      visitor_lon = google.loader.ClientLocation.longitude;
      visitor_city = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.city;
  visitor_region = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.region;
  visitor_country = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country;
      visitor_countrycode = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country_code;

      document.getElementById('yourinfo').innerHTML = visitor_lat;

    }
    else
    {

      // We implemented the Maxmind method (See source code) or you may want to just leave a message:
      document.getElementById('yourinfo').innerHTML = '<p>Whoops we couldnt find you!</p>';
    }
```

I used this code for finding the current location of each visitor .But the google.loader.ClientLocation  returns null value.Is there any other way to find the location of visitor.Please help me.

Comment: Wasn't this API abandoned years ago, browsers have geolocation now ?

Answer (score 0):

try this: **HTML5 - Using Geolocation**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo">Click the button to get your coordinates:</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
} else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
}
}

function showPosition(position) {
x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
"<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  
}
```